# Blank value returned for the pyqt4 lineEdit

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I apologize if this is a simple/stupid error or already been answered, I am very new to programming and i am educating myself. This is my first Question in stackoverflow, so please do let me know if you need further information or my question is not clear.

My code is not able to retrieve the IP address that I enter in my lineEdit Field.On the function "readip", I am trying to get the value of lineEdit but I never get the value I type in.I tried ip=str(gui.lineEdit.text()) and ip=str(gui.lineEdit.text). The ip=str(gui.lineEdit.text) gives me the memory slot of the object but not the ip address.

I am attaching the code from my Application. Please tell me  what I am doing wrong

This is my Main Application :

```
import Gui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import PyQt4
import subprocess
import time
import os
import sys
from threading import Thread



class Gui(QDialog,Gui.Ui_mGui):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        global ip

        super(Gui,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connect(self.instructionButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.showInstructions)
        Gui.connect(self.serviceButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), backendServiceClass)
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.autostartService)


        if self.checkBox.isChecked():

            print "The AutoStartService Button was checked"
            #backendService()

        else:
            print "The AutoStartService Button was not checked"




    def readip(self):
        global ip
        gui=Gui()
        ip=str(gui.lineEdit.text())
        print ip
        time.sleep(1)
        print"test"
        print ip
        time.sleep(20)



    def showInstructions(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self,"Instructions","Enter the IP address of a mobile device you carry with you always.The Application would check whether it can reach that device using your wireless network. If the device is unreachable, it would put the computer to sleep!")

    def autostartService(self):
        if self.checkBox.isChecked():
            autoStartService=1
            TrackAutoStartService = open("AutoStartService", "w+")
            TrackAutoStartService.write(str(autoStartService))
            TrackAutoStartService.close
            print "Autostart Service Checked"
            print autoStartService
        else:
            autoStartService = 0
            TrackAutoStartService = open("AutoStartService", "w+")
            TrackAutoStartService.write(str(autoStartService))
            TrackAutoStartService.close
            print "Autostart Service Unchecked"
            print autoStartService

class backendServiceClass(Thread,Gui):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(Gui):
        global loop
        global ip


        Gui.readip()


        print ip

        print ip

        TrackIP = open("TrackIP", "w+")
        TrackIP.write(ip)
        TrackIP.close
        if loop==1:
            loop=0
            #Gui.serviceButton.setText("Start Service")
        else:
            loop=1
            #Gui.serviceButton.setText("Stop Service")

        print("ping -n 1 -w 1000 " + ip)
        down = 0





        while loop==1:
            try:
                response = subprocess.check_output(
                    ['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '2000', ip],
                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,  # get all output
                    universal_newlines=True,  # return string not bytes
                    shell=True,
                    creationflags=subprocess.SW_HIDE
                )
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                response = None

            if (response != None):
                down = 0
                time.sleep(1)
                print ("The host" + ip + " is Alive!")

            else:
                down = down + 1
                time.sleep(1)
                print (down)
                if (down == 10):
                    print ("a total of " + str(down) + "pings has been lost")
                    down = 0
                    time.sleep(10)
                    os.system("shutdown -h")




global loop
loop=0
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
form=Gui()
form.show()




app.exec_()
```

Below is the Gui.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Gui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_mGui(object):
    def setupUi(self, mGui):
        mGui.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mGui"))
        mGui.resize(246, 308)
        mGui.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(246, 308))
        mGui.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(246, 309))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/image/logo.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        mGui.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(mGui)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 201, 20))
        f = open("AutoStartService", "r+")
        AutoStartService = int(f.read())
        if AutoStartService == 1:
            self.checkBox.setChecked(True)
        else:
            self.checkBox.setChecked(False)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox"))
        self.SleeperLabel = QtGui.QLabel(mGui)
        self.SleeperLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 131, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Harlow Solid Italic"))
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.SleeperLabel.setFont(font)
        self.SleeperLabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SleeperLabel"))
        self.SleeperLabel_2 = QtGui.QLabel(mGui)
        self.SleeperLabel_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 71, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Harlow Solid Italic"))
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.SleeperLabel_2.setFont(font)
        self.SleeperLabel_2.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.SleeperLabel_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/image/logo64x64.png")))
        self.SleeperLabel_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SleeperLabel_2"))
        self.serviceButton = QtGui.QPushButton(mGui)
        self.serviceButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 260, 101, 31))
        self.serviceButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("serviceButton"))
        self.instructionButton = QtGui.QPushButton(mGui)
        self.instructionButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 260, 101, 31))
        self.instructionButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("instructionButton"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(mGui)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 210, 151, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(mGui)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 171, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.checkBox_2 = QtGui.QCheckBox(mGui)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 221, 20))
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_2"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(mGui)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 151, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(mGui)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 98, 181, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))

        self.retranslateUi(mGui)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mGui)

    def retranslateUi(self, mGui):
        mGui.setWindowTitle(_translate("mGui", "Sleeper V3.0", None))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("mGui", "Autostart Service at Application start", None))
        self.SleeperLabel.setText(_translate("mGui", "Sleeper", None))
        self.serviceButton.setText(_translate("mGui", "Start Service", None))
        self.instructionButton.setText(_translate("mGui", "Instructions", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("mGui", "Currently Tracking the device :", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("mGui", "IP Address of your Mobile Device", None))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("mGui", "Autostart Application at System Startup", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("mGui", "Service Status :", None))
        f1 = open("TrackIP", "r+")
        IP = str(f1.read())
        if IP != "":
            self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("mGui", IP, None))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("mGui", "Mobile IP", None))

import xz_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys



    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mGui = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_mGui()
    ui.setupUi(mGui)
    mGui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please let me know if you need further information

Comment: in `readip()`, there is no need to create a new `Gui` instance. Use `self`:  `self.lineEdit.text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to be honest, there are many flaws in your code. Your problem comes from it.

- `global loop`

You don't have to use global variables. You can pass them to class      through constructor and save as instance variables.

- `Gui.connect(self.serviceButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
                  backendServiceClass)`

Instead of creating and starting object on click you better create it in Gui constructor and start it on click.

`# Gui init
self.service = backendServiceClass(parent=self)
...
self.serviceButton.clicked.connect(self.service.start)`

- `class backendServiceClass(Thread, Gui):`

Do not inherit from Gui.

- `class backendServiceClass(Thread, Gui):
  ...
      def run(Gui):
  ....
          Gui.readip()`

This is your problem. Despite renaming `self` variable to `Gui`, it still points to your `backendServiceClass` instance. And, because you inherited from Gui class, it have `lineEdit` object. But it's not the same `lineEdit` that you change.

**UPDATE:**

I modified your code a little bit, so here is a working code:

Gui.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Gui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8


    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


class Ui_mGui(object):
    def setupUi(self, mGui):
        mGui.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mGui"))
        mGui.resize(246, 308)
        mGui.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(246, 308))
        mGui.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(246, 309))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/image/logo.png")),
                       QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        mGui.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(mGui)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 201, 20))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox"))
        self.SleeperLabel = QtGui.QLabel(mGui)
        self.SleeperLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 131, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Harlow Solid Italic"))
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.SleeperLabel.setFont(font)
        self.SleeperLabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SleeperLabel"))
        self.SleeperLabel_2 = QtGui.QLabel(mGui)
        self.SleeperLabel_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 71, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Harlow Solid Italic"))
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.SleeperLabel_2.setFont(font)
        self.SleeperLabel_2.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.SleeperLabel_2.setPixmap(
            QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/image/logo64x64.png")))
        self.SleeperLabel_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SleeperLabel_2"))
        self.serviceButton = QtGui.QPushButton(mGui)
        self.serviceButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 260, 101, 31))
        self.serviceButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("serviceButton"))
        self.instructionButton = QtGui.QPushButton(mGui)
        self.instructionButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 260, 101, 31))
        self.instructionButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("instructionButton"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(mGui)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 210, 151, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(mGui)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 171, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.checkBox_2 = QtGui.QCheckBox(mGui)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 221, 20))
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_2"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(mGui)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 151, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(mGui)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 98, 181, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))

        self.retranslateUi(mGui)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mGui)

    def retranslateUi(self, mGui):
        mGui.setWindowTitle(_translate("mGui", "Sleeper V3.0", None))
        self.checkBox.setText(
            _translate("mGui", "Autostart Service at Application start", None))
        self.SleeperLabel.setText(_translate("mGui", "Sleeper", None))
        self.serviceButton.setText(_translate("mGui", "Start Service", None))
        self.instructionButton.setText(
            _translate("mGui", "Instructions", None))
        self.label.setText(
            _translate("mGui", "Currently Tracking the device :", None))
        self.label_2.setText(
            _translate("mGui", "IP Address of your Mobile Device", None))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(
            _translate("mGui", "Autostart Application at System Startup",
                       None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("mGui", "Service Status :", None))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("mGui", "Mobile IP", None))
```

Main app

```
import subprocess
import time
import os
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from Gui import Ui_mGui


class Gui(QDialog, Ui_mGui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Gui, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        f = open("AutoStartService", "r+")
        AutoStartService = int(f.read())
        if AutoStartService == 1:
            self.checkBox.setChecked(True)
        else:
            self.checkBox.setChecked(False)
        f.close()

        f = open("TrackIP", "r+")
        IP = str(f.read())
        if IP != "":
            self.lineEdit.setText(IP)
        f.close()

        self.service = backendServiceClass(parent=self)

        self.connect(self.instructionButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
                     self.showInstructions)
        Gui.connect(self.serviceButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
                    lambda: self.service.toggle_service(self.lineEdit.text()))
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.autostartService)

        if self.checkBox.isChecked():
            print "The AutoStartService Button was checked"
            # backendService()
        else:
            print "The AutoStartService Button was not checked"

    def showInstructions(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Instructions",
                                "Enter the IP address of a mobile device you carry with you always.The Application would check whether it can reach that device using your wireless network. If the device is unreachable, it would put the computer to sleep!")

    def autostartService(self):
        if self.checkBox.isChecked():
            autoStartService = 1
            print "Autostart Service Checked"
        else:
            autoStartService = 0
            print "Autostart Service Unchecked"
        print autoStartService

        TrackAutoStartService = open("AutoStartService", "w+")
        TrackAutoStartService.write(str(autoStartService))
        TrackAutoStartService.close()


class backendServiceClass(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.daemon = True
        self.ip = None

    def toggle_service(self, ip):
        if self.isRunning():
            self.terminate()
            self.parent().serviceButton.setText("Start Service")
        else:
            self.parent().serviceButton.setText("Stop Service")
            self.ip = str(ip)
            self.start()

    def run(self):
        TrackIP = open("TrackIP", "w+")
        TrackIP.write(self.ip)
        TrackIP.close()
        print("ping -n 1 -w 1000 " + self.ip)
        down = 0

        while 1:
            try:
                response = subprocess.check_output(
                    ['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '2000', self.ip],
                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,  # get all output
                    universal_newlines=True,  # return string not bytes
                    shell=True,
                    creationflags=subprocess.SW_HIDE
                )
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                response = None

            if (response != None):
                down = 0
                time.sleep(1)
                print ("The host" + self.ip + " is Alive!")

            else:
                down = down + 1
                time.sleep(1)
                print (down)
                if (down == 10):
                    print ("a total of " + str(down) + "pings has been lost")
                    down = 0
                    time.sleep(10)
                    os.system("shutdown -h")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Gui()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```